# Unable to set flag in /etc/sysconfig/kubelet via clusterdeploy.yaml

Tags: kubernetes, kubelet

Team,

I am trying to specify the authentication-token-webhook flag on kubelet. 
so, I manually add the flag in /etc/sysconfig/kubelet and restart the service. then it works.

Is there a specific way to add that flag in `cluster.yaml` file that it gets added to kubelet automatically and I don't have to manually add it.

My changes in `cluster.yaml` look like this

```
kubelet:
    featureGates:
      DevicePlugins: "true"
```

so shall i add it as 
kubelet:
    featureGates:
      DevicePlugins: "true"
    authentication-token-webhook

Kubelet output after adding manually looks like this:

```
lab@10:~$ ps -ax | grep kubel | grep web
 5188 ?        Ssl    0:17 /usr/local/bin/kube-apiserver --address=127.0.0.1 --admission-control=Initializers,NamespaceLifecycle,LimitRanger,ServiceAccount,PersistentVolumeLabel,DefaultStorageClass,DefaultTolerationSeconds,MutatingAdmissionWebhook,ValidatingAdmissionWebhook,NodeRestriction,ResourceQuota --allow-privileged=true --anonymous-auth=false --apiserver-count=1 --authentication-token-webhook-config-file=/srv/kubernetes/assets/webhook-auth.yaml --authorization-mode=RBAC --basic-auth-file=/srv/kubernetes/basic_auth.csv --client-ca-file=/srv/kubernetes/ca.crt --cloud-provider=external --etcd-quorum-read=false --etcd-servers-overrides=/events#http://127.0.0.1:4002 --etcd-servers=http://127.0.0.1:4001 --insecure-port=8080 --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP,Hostname,ExternalIP --proxy-client-cert-file=/srv/kubernetes/apiserver-aggregator.cert --proxy-client-key-file=/srv/kubernetes/apiserver-aggregator.key --requestheader-allowed-names=aggregator --requestheader-client-ca-file=/srv/kubernetes/apiserver-aggregator-ca.cert --requestheader-extra-headers-prefix=X-Remote-Extra- --requestheader-group-headers=X-Remote-Group --requestheader-username-headers=X-Remote-User --secure-port=443 --service-cluster-ip-range=100.64.0.0/13 --storage-backend=etcd2 --tls-cert-file=/srv/kubernetes/server.cert --tls-private-key-file=/srv/kubernetes/server.key --token-auth-file=/srv/kubernetes/known_tokens.csv --v=2
 7250 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/local/bin/kubelet --allow-privileged=true --authentication-token-webhook --cgroup-root=/ --cloud-provider=external --cluster-dns=100.64.0.10 --cluster-domain=cluster.local --enable-debugging-handlers=true --eviction-hard=memory.available<100Mi,nodefs.available<10%,nodefs.inodesFree<5%,imagefs.available<10%,imagefs.inodesFree<5% --feature-gates=DevicePlugins=true,ExperimentalCriticalPodAnnotation=true --kubeconfig=/var/lib/kubelet/kubeconfig --network-plugin=cni --node-labels=kops.k8s.io/instancegroup=master-a,kubernetes.io/role=master,node-role.kubernetes.io/master= --non-masquerade-cidr=100.64.0.0/10 --pod-infra-container-image=k8s.gcr.io/pause-amd64:3.0 --pod-manifest-path=/etc/kubernetes/manifests --register-schedulable=true --register-with-taints=node-role.kubernetes.io/master=:NoSchedule --v=2 --cni-bin-dir=/opt/cni/bin/ --cni-conf-dir=/etc/cni/net.d/
```

Comment: There's not enough information here, how are you deploying? What is using cluster.yaml?

Comment: cluster.yaml? This looks like kubespray. What are you using to create this k8s cluster?

Comment: never mind resolved it myself.

Comment: Would You care to share the solution @Afar? Others might have encountered similar problem and your solution might be helpful.

Comment: so how to answer? I can't answer my own right?

Comment: @Afar of course you can answer your own question if nobody else posted the solution to your problem. Instead of adding a comment add an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flag needs to be added in this file manually 
`cat /etc/sysconfig/kubelet`

or via cluster deployment file as below:
  kubelet:
    featureGates:
      DevicePlugins: "true"
    authenticationTokenWebhook: true

then also specify the CA cert to use
fileAssets:
  - name: webhook-auth-ca.pem
    roles: ["Master"]
    content: |
      -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

and finally the auth file
- name: webhook-auth.yaml
    roles: ["Master"]
    content: |
      clusters: